# Default, building parameters for Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I want to install zabbix (server and java-gateway) 3.2 from sources (needed to patch something). What are default parameters that i should use with  `./configure` command so it would be same as installing using packages ?

Comment: what package..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
--enable-server --enable-java --enable-ipv6 --with-jabber --with-libxml2 --with-unixodbc --with-net-snmp --with-ssh2 --with-openipmi --with-ldap --with-libcurl
```

For encryption, choose one of `--with-mbedtls`, `--with-gnutls` or `--with-openssl`.

Also add one for the database used, like `--with-mysql`.

Note that you will need quite a lot of development packages.

Comment: Thanks. And is it possible to build it ("configure") on one machine and then install on the other one (that doesn't need to have all of these development packages)?

Comment: Sure - but the runtime (libcurl, libnetsnmp etc) dependencies must still be present. The *-dev packages are only needed on the box where the compilation takes place.